# Not able to play video file in Qt5 based Web browser on Linux ARM machine

Tags: ffmpeg, qtwebkit, yocto, qt5.4, qtgstreamer

I am using Yocto Buildsystem to generate customized Linux Image with Qt5.4 
support in it for TI AM335x based ARM platform, here in Yocto I have selected 
components those are required for Qt5 based Webbrowser so as to play HTML5 audio
and video files such as:
- qtmultimedia
- gstreamer (1.0)
- qtscript
- qtwebsockets
- qtimageformats
- libgles-omap3
- lighttpd 
- gst-ffmpeg
- gst-fluendo-mp3
- gstreamer (0.10)

Here after building the final image. I found that there are 
both gstreamer and gstreamer-1.0 directories in /usr/lib, also the 
required ffmpeg libs are located in /usr/lib/gstreamer directory.
But I suspect the webkit by default links to /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0
directory and hence cannot find required libs.

When I tried the manually copy the ffmepg related libs in /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0
directory from /usr/lib/gstreamer, then I got the libav related version error.

Please guide me regarding who to configure webkit or webcore .bb file so that
it links to both the gstreamer directories in /usr/lib and can thus play 
HTML5 audio and video files in qt5 based web-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more information about your bblayers, your local.conf?

Have you enabled GStreamer in QtMultimedia?
If not, please add this line into your local.conf.
`PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qtmultimedia = " gstreamer010 gstreamer"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the same in my local.conf but still audio video files wont play on qt5 based webbrowser.

Comment: It turns out my that my video plays but there would be no sound in youtube. Similar problem to yours.

Comment: I just found out that there is a pulseaudio configuration in the Qt Recipe, you will need to add that if you want to have sound.

Comment: I tried playing the video from youtube, though I am able to see the individual static image frame, but video does not play and it keeps buffering.

Comment: I tried to debug my custom made qt browser on my host machine x86. Here video audio plays perfectly fine, I found that as video play starts first library loaded is "libgstplaybin". In my Yocto BSP I found the required "libgstplaybin" and "libgstdecodebin" in /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10, but these are not present for gstreamer-1.0, I guess probably this might be the issue. I am currently looking into this.